# PHP creating an array from another array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop

Hi I was wondering how to create an array with key value pairs from my other array which is an array consisting of values read in from a DB table.

Heres the code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT phone, id FROM table1 GROUP BY id";
$result1 = $mysqli->query($query1);

while($rows = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

}
```

In order to see the array I used fwrite and var_export

Heres the var_export($row,1):

```
array('phone' => 123, 'id' => 456)  
array('phone' => 246, 'id' => 789)
```

What am looking for is to create another array using those values to look like this:

```
array(  
   123 => 456  
   246 => 789)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$newArray = array();
while($rows = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newArray[$rows['phone']] = $rows['id'];
}
```

The new array will then look like this:

```
array(  
   123 => 456  
   246 => 789
)
```

Comment: Note the fetch mode: `fetch_assoc`, best use `$newArray[$rows['phone']] = $rows['id']`